# Contact form (Php and html

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

So I've been using a contact form, I created some php and html form but it sends everything to my email, except the email that the user puts in the form. Been trying all the stuff below, nothing works yet

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$message;

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
            <form action="contact.php" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="25" cols="10" placeholder="  Message Texts..."></textarea>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: There seems to be no error in the code you have provided, though can you verify by adding `echo $email;` to check if the value is being received or not.

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a noob, but I am. Where would I add that

Comment: You need to add `name`-tags to your input fields. Without them, they won't be posted. Example: `<input type="text" name="email" ...`

Comment: Again, please tell me where, I really suck at coding

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing, if the name tags are the issue. Anyways try adding it right after `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: By name tags we mean, `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">` like add `name="<element_name>"` within the input tag

Comment: You might want to look into a basic tutorial about HTML forms... the `name`-tag is the name you use to fetch it with `$_POST` in PHP. So no `name`-tag, no `$_POST`-data.

Comment: I added the name tags, still same issue

Comment: Did the echo yield any output?

Comment: Nothing happened, but I completed the form and received this in my email    From: test
E-mail:
Message: asdasd

Comment: Oh sorry, remove or comment out those javascripts (`window.location...`) to see the output

Comment: Did that, received no email or anything at all

Comment: You might want to replace your email here with "example@domain.com" to avoid spam

Comment: Anyone? not sure why this is happening

Comment: Replace your whole php with just this `<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>` and see the browser output, not your mails. If it displays the email then the value is being sent, else something is wrong with HTML part not PHP.

Comment: Did that, entered the form with random information, hit sent and the form cleared like it normally does

Comment: Would be nice if possible, if someone could just provide me a new php contact form it only needs to be basic

Comment: Are you using jQuery Ajax? If yes, please add the complete code

Comment: No I am not using jQuery Ajax

Comment: I'm not able to figure this out with this part of code. Can you mail me the php and html pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through your **script.js** file, I finally figured out the problem. The variable sent is not `email` while its `emaild`. So your PHP correction would be:

```
$email = $_POST['emaild'];
```

Comment: Btw, you are using jQuery Ajax.

Comment: Do I change anything under the html file and your sure the php is "emaild" cause I am not receiving any email now

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Comment: I would +1 it but my rep is too low, Thanks so much it really helped

Comment: Accepting my answer would do :)